# $End_k(M ⊗_k K) \simeq K$

Tags: modules, representation-theory, group-rings

Let $G$ be a finite group, $k$ be an algebraically closed field such that $char(k)\nmid |G|$ and K/k be a field extension.
If M is any simple $k[G]$-module show $End_k(M ⊗_k K) \simeq K$

What I've done so far is: Since $M$ is a $k[G]$-module, $M$ is also a $k$-module, so $M\simeq k^d$ for some $d$ as a $k$-vector space.
So $$M ⊗_k K \simeq k^d ⊗_k K\simeq \bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^{d}(k ⊗_k K) \simeq \bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^{d} K \simeq K^d$$
and hence $$End_k(M ⊗_k K)\simeq End_k(K^d).$$

And this is where I get stuck.
I assume that probably this isn't really the way to go, since I haven't even used the simplicity of $M$ somewhere, but I really have no other idea on how to approach this.
Can anyone give me any hints/point out where I might be wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems very likely that you are not working with the correct statement. Probably you mean $End_{K[G]}(M \otimes_k K) \simeq K$?

Comment: @CaptainLama The exercise says what I've written but its probably wrong you are right, because if for example $K=k$ and $dim_k M=2$ then, obviously $End_k (M ⊗_k K) = End_k (k^2) \simeq$ 2x2 matrices with coefs in k.
But if the correct one is the one you've stated, then how would I proceed.
I know that for M simple, k alg. closed then $End_{k[G]}(M)\simeq k$

Comment: $M$ is a representation of $G$ with coefficients in $k$. So it suffices to check that $M\otimes_kK$, which is a representation $G$ with coefficients in $K$ remains irreducible. Then the claim would follow from Schur's lemma.

Comment: @KentaS wouldn't Schur's Lemma give me information about $End_{K[G]}$ instead of $End_k$ ?

Comment: Well, as the version with End_K is obviously false. Do you mean End_k[G] or End_K[G]? The version with End_K[G] is just Schur's lemma, as in my previous comment.

Comment: @KentaS Schur's Lemma would require that  $K$ is also algebraically closed but I assume any extension of an algebraically closed field is also algebraically closed.
Other than that, thank you both for your answers

Comment: No, for example $\mathbb C(x)/\mathbb C$ is not algebraically closed. You have to modify the proof of Schur's lemma.

Comment: @KentaS I don't see how I can modify it in order to get $End_K[G](A)\simeq K$ for some A simple $K[G]$-mod. The only thing I see is that the ring will be a division ring

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $M$ reduces over $K$, then there exists a nonconstant linear map $f\colon M\otimes_kK\to M\otimes_kK$ such that $f\circ \rho(g)=\rho(g)\circ f$ for all $g\in G$. Here $f\in\hom_K(M\otimes_kK,M\otimes_kK)=\hom_k(M,M)\otimes_kK$ commuting with $\rho(g)$ is a linear condition with coefficients in $k$. Thus there is also a nonconstant solution $f_0\in\hom_k(M,M)$ to these linear equations (by for example choosing a linear section $K\to k$).

But since $k$ is algebraically closed, a non-constant map $f_0\colon M\to M$ of $G$-representations means that $M$ is reducible over $k$ (by choosing an eigenspace of $f_0$), a contradiction.